# Taylor polynomials: Why does $R_{n,x_0}(x) = o(|x-x_0|^n)\implies \lim_{x\rightarrow x_0}R_{n,x_0}= 0$?

Tags: calculus, taylor-expansion

Given a remainder term $R_{n,x_0}(x)$ of a n-degree Taylor polynomial at $x_0$ $$f(x) = T_{n,x_0}f(x)+R_{n,x_0}f(x)$$

Why does $$R_{n,x_0}(x) = o(|x-x_0|^n)\implies lim_{x\rightarrow x_0}Rn_{n,x_0}= 0$$

where $o()$ is the little-o, i.e.

$$R_{n,x_0}(x) = o(|x-x_0|^n) \iff \lim_{x\rightarrow x_0}\frac{R_{n,x_0}(x)}{|x-x_0]^n} = 0$$

Comment: Are you satisfied with the answer below?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consider the following as assumptions

$$\eqalign{
  & \mathop {\lim }\limits_{x \to {x_0}} {{f(x)} \over {g(x)}} = 0\,\,\,\,\,\,\, \leftrightarrow \,\,\,\,f(x) = o\left( {g(x)} \right)  \cr 
  & \mathop {\lim }\limits_{x \to {x_0}} {{g(x)} \over {h(x)}} = 0\,\,\,\,\,\,\, \leftrightarrow \,\,\,\,g(x) = o\left( {h(x)} \right) \cr} $$

then it follows directly that

$$f(x) = o\left( {o\left( {h(x)} \right)} \right)$$

Now by **limit theorem for products** one can write

$$\mathop {\lim }\limits_{x \to {x_0}} {{f(x)} \over {g(x)}}\mathop {\lim }\limits_{x \to {x_0}} {{g(x)} \over {h(x)}} = \mathop {\lim }\limits_{x \to {x_0}} \left( {{{f(x)} \over {g(x)}}{{g(x)} \over {h(x)}}} \right) = \mathop {\lim }\limits_{x \to {x_0}} \left( {{{f(x)} \over {h(x)}}} \right) = 0$$

and hence

$$f(x) = o(h(x))$$

and finally concluding that

$$o\left( {o\left( {h(x)} \right)} \right) = o\left( {h(x)} \right)$$

Now to relate this to your question we know that

$$\eqalign{
  & {R_{n,{x_0}}}(x) = o\left( {{{\left| {x - {x_0}} \right|}^n}} \right)  \cr 
  & {\left| {x - {x_0}} \right|^n} = o\left( 1 \right) \cr} $$

and hence

$${R_{n,{x_0}}}(x) = o\left( {o\left( 1 \right)} \right) = o\left( 1 \right)$$

which simply means

$$\mathop {\lim }\limits_{x \to {x_0}} {R_{n,{x_0}}}(x) = 0$$

but it **doesn't** mean $${R_{n,{x_0}}}(x) = 0$$

Comment: Can't you also use Squeeze theorem already on the second inequality?

Comment: Yes you can. So what? It doesn't give you what you want!

Comment: See the question (the direction of the $\implies$).

Comment: See the edited answer there.

Comment: Yeah I see that my question had a "bug" as well.